# Installation of Oracle 9.2.4.0 stalled

Tags: installation, oracle-9i, redhat

I'm installing Oracle 9.2.4.0 (I know, I know...) on Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 4 (Nahant Update 8) 64 bits using an Oracle 32 bit installer.

It appears to be stalled or hanged at 17% while *"Installing Required Support Files 32 bit"* indicating *"linking pending"*.

[image]

This is what the log says as of now:

```
[oracle9@xxxx]$ tail -f installActions2007-09-24_07-34-38PM.log
    copyAsText = null
    JarLoc = /tmp/OraInstall2007-09-24_07-34-38PM/temp36
    gpEntries = [[libvsn_ee9.a ->%ORACLE_HOME%/lib32/libvsn9.a 2214 plats=2=>[46] langs=2=>[en,fr,ar,bn,pt_BR,bg,fr_CA,ca,hr,cs,da,nl,ar_EG,en_GB,et,fi,de,el,iw,hu,is,in,it,ja,ko,es,lv,lt,ms,es_MX,no,pl,pt,ro,ru,zh_CN,sk,sl,es_ES,sv,th,zh_TW,tr,uk,vi]]
, [libntcps9.a ->%ORACLE_HOME%/lib32/libntcps9.a 52696 plats=2=>[46] langs=2=>[en,fr,ar,bn,pt_BR,bg,fr_CA,ca,hr,cs,da,nl,ar_EG,en_GB,et,fi,de,el,iw,hu,is,in,it,ja,ko,es,lv,lt,ms,es_MX,no,pl,pt,ro,ru,zh_CN,sk,sl,es_ES,sv,th,zh_TW,tr,uk,vi]]
, [naeet.o ->%ORACLE_HOME%/lib32/naeet.o 6029 plats=2=>[46] langs=2=>[en,fr,ar,bn,pt_BR,bg,fr_CA,ca,hr,cs,da,nl,ar_EG,en_GB,et,fi,de,el,iw,hu,is,in,it,ja,ko,es,lv,lt,ms,es_MX,no,pl,pt,ro,ru,zh_CN,sk,sl,es_ES,sv,th,zh_TW,tr,uk,vi]]
]
    DllGroup = false

Llamando acción unixActions2.2.0.18.0  touchFile
    source = /folderA/oracle/folderB/OraHome1/lib/ldflags
```

We've successfully installed Ora9i 32 bits in a 64 bit servers before.

What do you think is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has worked for me:

- Abort the installation an set the following environtment variable: `LD_ASSUME_KERNEL=2.4.1`, This will get you past the 17% mark.
- Later during the installation you will get this error:

[image]

This happens because the installer is using the 64 bit bcc library

- So solve that you must do this as root:

  `cd /usr/bin
  mv gcc gcc_old
  cp gcc32 gcc`

Then click on Retry. Remember to revert that change after successfully installing.